# Expression simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have this term

```
Sqrt[(B Bc)/(A^2-B Bc)]Sqrt[B Bc+A(-A+Sqrt[A^2-B Bc])]Sqrt[-B Bc+A(A + Sqrt[A^2-B Bc])],
```

which actually can be simplified to B*Bc. However, it seems Mathematica cannot simplify it. Any suggestions on how I'd be able to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Version

"12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Sqrt[(B Bc)/(A^2 - B Bc)] Sqrt[
    B Bc + A (-A + Sqrt[A^2 - B Bc])] Sqrt[-B Bc + A (A + Sqrt[A^2 - B Bc])];
```

Require all of the arguments of [`Sqrt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt.html) to be positive

```
cons = FullSimplify[And @@ Cases[expr, Sqrt[z_] :> (z > 0), Infinity]]

(* B Bc + A Sqrt[A^2 - B Bc] > A^2 *)

Simplify[expr, cons]

(* B Bc *)
```

Comment: It is better to use `cons=Reduce[Cases[y, Sqrt[z_] :> (z > 0), Infinity]]` yielding `a > 0 && 0 < b < a^2`. The `FullSimplify` produces a spurious wrong condition `a == 0 && b > 0`, which upon use in `Simplify` yields `-b`. Notice, that I replace `A->a` and `B Bc ->b`. Another way to see an issue with your method is to realize that `cons` produced by `FullSimplify` contains `Sqrt` the argument of which also needs to be tested for positivity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is why:

```
y=Sqrt[a (a+Sqrt[a^2-b])-b] Sqrt[a (-a+Sqrt[a^2-b])+b] Sqrt[b/(a^2-b)]
FullSimplify[y,Assumptions->a>0&&b>0&&a^2-b>0]
(*b*)

Plot[{y/.{b->-1},y/.{b->1}},{a,-2,2},
 PlotTheme->{"BoldColor","Frame"},
 PlotLegends->{-1,1},
 PlotStyle->{Thickness[0.03],Directive[Thickness[0.01]]}]
```

[image]